# Guice: bootstrapping and dependency graph resolution

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I've read that explicitly requesting an object instance from a DI mechanism is considered a general anti-pattern for DI/IoC. This is because, by the time the object comes into scope, it should have already been injected with all the dependencies it needs. In Guice-land, such an anti-pattern would be represented as:

```
Service svcImpl = (Service)injector.getInstance(Service.class);
```

Apparently, the one exception to this anti-pattern is the bootstrapping/dependency resolution phase, where you ask Guice for all the top-level *root* ("root" in the sense that all other objects flow from it) objects.

Interestingly enough, I can't find any practical, working code examples of this bootstrap process after an exhaustive online search!  I would *imagine* it looks something like this:

```
public void bootstrap() {
    RootObj1 root1 = (RootObj1)injector.getInstance(RootObj1.class);
    RootObj2 root2 = (RootObj2)injector.getInstance(RootObj2.class);

    this.root1 = root1;
    this.root2 = root2;

    // Since all objects flow from these two "root" dependencies, bootstrapping
    // is complete. root1 and root2 contain all the dependencies the application
    // needs from here on out, and the "injector" object is no longer needed.
    // More importantly, injector is never used anywhere else in the code, and
    // therefore the code is not in violation of this anti-pattern.
}
```

**Is this correct, or am I way off-base here?** I ask only because I can't find any working examples!!

As I write this I'm beginning to second-guess myself because this just doesn't seem feasible/practical.

This is because, in reality an application's dependency graph will be massive with many separate, disparate "dependency trees", each with their own roots. This would lead to the necessity for some kind of `Bootstrapper` object, responsible for returning the roots of each of these trees so that all other objects across the codebase could request the appropriate root object to the "tree" they belong to. This is already sounding extremely convoluded.

A **working code example** of how bootstrapping is practiced in the real world might help bring some clarity to this for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you're having a hard time finding a good example is because you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  The bootstrapping is no more complicated than your code snippet, except that you'd probably need to invoke a method on `root1` or `root2` to have your application begin doing whatever it does!

The rest is just handled by Guice.  Any object that gets instantiated during the course of execution gets what it needs from Guice, via an `@Inject`-annotated constructor (or methods).  There is no need to have a Boostrapper object that controls all roots of all trees, because the DI container manages all the instances.  If an object from one tree requires an object in another, you just `@Inject` it!  No need to "ask" a Bootstrapper object for it.  This is sometimes hard to conceive for someone with a `ServiceLocator` background, but it really is a far more cohesive way to design classes.

Guice has several tools for managing dependency graphs.  Disparate dependency trees are managed through **modules**, which are just sets of cohesive bindings.  Guice thus encourages you to encapsulate functionality and let the injector resolve interdependencies.  Also, Guice doesn't instantiate a graph until it's needed (with the exception of singletons, which can be eagerly loaded), and a developer can explicitly delay instantiation using `Provider` interfaces and methods.

Maybe it would help if you explained what kind of application you're wanting to use Guice for, or explain what kinds of applications you're used to.  That would give us a better idea of what doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @Ryan! But I'm still confused: my understanding of Guice was that it is not alone sufficient to just mark something with `@Inject` - that you have to *also* let Guice create an instance of that object (by interrogating the module). Is that not correct?!? If not, then what's the purpose of ever creating an `Injector` instance? If it is correct, then that's the root of my confusion: how to use `Injector.getInstance()` to inject the "roots" of your dependency graph, so that all other objects (flowing from the roots) are auto-injected at runtime.

Comment: Actually it _is_ sufficient to simply annotate with `@Inject`.  No need to interrogate the module.  The only purpose of the Injector is to bootstrap the application.  After you've created the injector and accessed the root object, that's the last time you should really need it.